# Can't get a handle on a Django ManyToMany Model object

Tags: python, django

I have a simple example of a Member, and a MemberGroup class in a Django app.  I would like the following data representation, but I'm not sure if I'm complicating things by using a ManyToMany relationship:

Member:
1 - Member1
2 - Member2
3 - Member3
Group:
 
1 - Group1
2 - Group2
3 - Group3
MemberGroup:
 
1 - Member1/Group1
 
2 - Member1/Group2
 
3 - Member2/Group3, etc.

I have the following classes:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class MemberGroup(models.Model):
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'd like to be able to use the combo of id/member/group in other model classes (say maybe BlogPost(MemberGroupId, post), but I'm not sure how to get a handle on that particular object. The current model generates the correct database tables, I'm just not sure how to get a handle on an object that represents the link table. In the Django shell, when I get MemberGroup(id=1) and try printing the member associated with that MemberGroup, I get

```
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x2ae6c10>
```

Do I need to create another class, Group, and then have Member and Group be foreign keys in the MemberGroup class to accomplish what I need or can I use my current setup?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: First, I'd rename the MemberGroup model to Groups, and MemberGroup.member to MemberGroup.members. But that's just for readability. Next, I think you tried to print Group.members, that gives you a ManyRelatedManager object. Try printing Group.get(pk=1).members.all(). That should return a list with all Members in Group 1. Read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reading the docs again related to the many_to_many relationship yielded the correct solution for me, which was using this "through" designation on a model.  My models now look like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('Member', related_name='created_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through="Membership")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group_name

class Membership(models.Model):
     member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
     group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
     join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     league_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return "%s (%s)" % (self.member, self.group)
```

and now I can get a handle on the Membership class where as before, the relationship was created, but there was no explicit object for me to use. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would do the models like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Member(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

Then you could do this:

```
>>> test_group = Group(group_name='Admin', description='Admin group')
>>> test_group.save()
>>> m1 = Member(nickname='Robert')
>>> m1.save()
>>> m1.groups.add(test_group)
>>> m1.save()
>>> m1.groups.all()
[<Group: Group object>]
>>> test_group.objects.get(group_name='Admin').member_set.all()
[<Member: Member object>]
```

That code creates a group "Admin", then a member "Robert".  It associates the "Robert" user to the "Admin" group.  I can then return all members of the "Admin" group using `member_set`.

EDIT: There's nothing exactly wrong with putting the `ManyToMany` field in the `Group` model to refer to the members, but it seems (to me, anyway) more logical to associate a member to a group rather than a group to a member.

Comment: User related_name in `groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name="members")` for more readability.
So you'll can do `group.members.all()`.